# Android: How can I launch shortcut of a certain app in my own application?

Tags: android, shortcut

I'm developing some kinds of beginner-level apps, and wondering if it is possible to launch a certain shortcut (not the app itself) in my own application.

Actually, I found the way that launch apps with their package names, but what I need to do is to start some shortcuts (which is located in my homescreen) when I touch the special button in my app.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your question makes no sense.  There is no such thing as launching a shortcut.  You can launch an app (in Android that would be starting the launcher activity).  But the idea of launching a shortcut doesn't make sense on any OS.

Comment: If you want to have specific [limited] functionality of other app in your app then that is definitely not a beginners-level app. Please clarify your question.

Comment: thanks guys. I realized that my question makes no sense when I checked your answers. Of course, there are no such things as launching shortcuts as you said. What I want to do is..let's assume a Windows OS. I create a shortcut, and I(my app) can launch the shortcut itself(if I input command "c:￦users￦desktop￦aaa.lnk") , not the .exe file even though the shortcut is linked with that executive file. 
I am wondering is there a way to "run a shortcut in my homescreen" programmatically, rather than a ".exe file in a directory in which the app was installed", figuratively speaking to Windows.

Comment: I think you guys may ask "why do you have to do that? just launch the app", but what I want to run is not same with. That shortcuts actually do specific  function of certain app, not just running the app.
Best regards.

Comment: @jhim have you find any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

May be useful, but how to get classes from manifest, I'd like to know
Please refer [link](https://web.archive.org/web/20200710235813/http://www.tutorialforandroid.com/2009/10/launching-other-application-using-code.html)

Say you want to open fuelgauge, to do this.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings","com.android.settings.fuelgauge.PowerUsageSummary");
intent.setComponent(cn);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity( intent);
```

**Explanation**
To open other people's application, you need to make sure that in their manifest file, the author specify the class to have the android.intent.action.MAIN intent-filter added to them.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
```

We then add category that this new intent will be launching something

```
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

Then we get identify the application we need to open by using ComponentName, here you specify the package name of the application as first argument and the class we want to open as the second one. You must understand that com.android.settings has a lot of classes that have Main intent-filter under it making the second argument to be the specific class that we need. (this is more than one line)

```
final ComponentName cn = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.fuelgauge.PowerUsageSummary");
```

After we identify the component we want, we set it to our intent

```
intent.setComponent(cn);
```

We then tell the intent that open opening this one make it as a new task

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

Then finally start our intent

```
startActivity( intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void createShortcut(@NonNull Activity activity, Class activityToOpen, String title,   int icon) {
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(activity, activityToOpen);
    shortcutIntent.setAction("android.intent.category.LAUNCHER");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.O) { // code for adding shortcut on pre oreo device
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, title);
        intent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
       // Parcelable parcelable = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(activity, icon);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,  icon);
        activity.sendBroadcast(intent);
        //System.out.println("added_to_homescreen");
    } else {
        ShortcutManager shortcutManager = activity.getSystemService(ShortcutManager.class);
        assert shortcutManager != null;
        if (shortcutManager.isRequestPinShortcutSupported()) {
            ShortcutInfo pinShortcutInfo =
                    new ShortcutInfo.Builder(activity, "idhere")
                            .setIntent(shortcutIntent)
                            .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(activity, icon))
                            .setShortLabel(title)
                            .build();

            shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(pinShortcutInfo, null);
            System.out.println("added_to_homescreen");
        } else {
            System.out.println("failed_to_add");
        }
    }
}
```